# Trouble with Button ng-click

Tags: html, angularjs

I am facing something a little bit weird. Well, at least for my understanding.

Let me give you the snippet, so you can see what I am doing

```js
var app = angular.module('riskQueries', []);
    
app.controller('cuitCtrl',function ($scope, $window) {
    
    $scope.defaultCuit = '--Inserte su CUIT aquí--';
    
    $scope.riskData = {
        cuit: null
    };
    
    $scope.reset = function () {
        $scope.riskData.cuit = angular.copy($scope.defaultCuit);
        $window.alert('Hey! You clicked!');
    };
    $scope.reset();
    $scope.comboData = {
        planAnterior: null,
        planSolicitado: null,
        options: [
            {id: 0, name: "No tengo un plan"},
            {id: 1, name: "Plan Básico"},
            {id: 2, name: "Plan Joven"},
            {id: 3, name: "Plan Famliar"},
            {id: 4, name: "Plan Cobertura Completa"},
            {id: 5, name: "Plan Plus"}
        ],
    };
    
});

app.filter('selectedPlan',function(){
    return function(planSolicitado,planAnterior){
        planAnterior <= planSolicitado;
    };
});
```

```css
input[type=text], select {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: "Verdana", sans-serif;
}

.submit {
    align-content: center;
    width: 30%;
    background-color: #71b9fb;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: "Verdana", sans-serif;
}

.submit:hover {
    background-color: #c4e3ff;
}

.form {
    width: 45%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: darkblue;
    border-width: thick;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 40px;
    font-family: "Verdana", sans-serif;
}

.header {
    border-bottom-style: groove;
    border-bottom-color: #9BE5F4;
    border-bottom-width: thick;
    width: 50.5%; 
}

.header .logo{
    max-width: 25%;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="logic.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

<body>
    <div class="header">
        <img class="logo">
    </div><br>
    <div class="form" ng-app="riskQueries" ng-controller="cuitCtrl">
        <form name="BPMForm">
          <label for="Cuit">CUIT/CUIL:</label>
          <input name="Cuit" type="text" ng-model="riskData.cuit"><br><br>
          <label for="PlanAnterior">Plan Actual:</label>
          <select name="PlanAnterior" id="PlanAnterior" ng-model="comboData.planAnterior" ng-options="option.name for option in comboData.options">
              <option value="">---Seleccione su plan Actual---</option>
          </select><br><br>
          <label for="PlanSolicitado">Plan Solicitado:</label>
          <select name="PlanSolicitado" id="PlanSolicitado" ng-model="comboData.planSolicitado" ng-options="option.name for option in comboData.options | filter: {id: '!' + comboData.planAnterior.id}">
              <option value="">---Seleccione su plan a Solicitar---</option>
          </select><br><br>
          <button class="submit" ng-click="reset()">Limpiar</button>
        </form>
        <p>resultados: WebService: {{riskResponse}} - cuit: {{riskData.cuit}} - planAnteior: {{comboData.planAnterior.id}} - planSolicitado: {{comboData.planSolicitado.id}}</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

If you run it, you can see that an alert box defined in the function I've created for my button is getting activated without me having clicked it. I think this maybe has something to do with where I declare the ng-app and ng-controller, but failed to find something useful.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're trying to call the reset() function, right? It seems you've called it right after declaring it on the controller.

```
$scope.reset = function () {
        $scope.riskData.cuit = angular.copy($scope.defaultCuit);
        $window.alert('Hey! You clicked!');
    };
    $scope.reset(); // <--- You're calling it here
    $scope.comboData = {
```

Remove the $scope.reset(); line from your controller and you should be good to go :)

Comment: Happens to everyone :)